# How to set image on Apple Watch notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch

Is there any process to set the image on Apple watch notification.?
I have tried adding in the image assets but did not find any clue.

Comment: What image are you talking about? The app icon or another image?

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that there really is a possibility to embed additional image in notification payload which is displayed by Watch (but not iPhone/iPad).

Somehow Pushover guys managed to do this.

[image: Pushover notification with image embedded]

But I don't know how they did it.
If I would get to know this I will post in answer edit.

Maybe you could ask them? (and post your conclusions here)

Answer (score 1):

In order to display an image from a payload (via a URL, I assume) in a notification, you'll need to create a subclass of `WKUserNotificationInterfaceController`, which Apple provides as a way to display dynamic notifications.

Although originally written for Swift 1.2, the tutorial at this link can show you how this can be done:

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-building-a-apple-watch-notification/